# How do I remove the first empty column in a CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've got an empty column at the start and can't work out why?

```
<ul class="inrpager clearfix">
  <li class="inrpager-previous"> </li>
  <li class="inrpager-title">Overview</li>
  <li class="inrpager-next">test</li>
</ul>
```

The css code maps a grid template

```
body.not-front ul.inrpager {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.8fr 1fr;
}
```

The result is that the content is mapped from the middle column.
Why is that?

[image]

Comment: No extra column is showing with the code you provided. Are you sure there aren't other style rules overriding these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.clearfix will probably be throwing in a ::before and possible an ::after with display table et all which does not play well with grid layout so..

css:

```
/* position absolute breaks it free and clear from the grid layout */
ul.inrpager.clearfix::before {
  position:absolute; 
}

ul.inrpager.clearfix::after {
  position:absolute; 
}
```

Comment: In my case, I had an `<svg>` element that was only in place to setup `<defs>` for later.  Setting `position:absolute` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an extra column.

It looks like the default margin or padding added by browsers to list elements.

Check the default styles on your `ul`.

Also see this [W3C default style sheet sample](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html):

[image]

Add this to your code:

```
ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because of `Clearfix` class you've used on `ul` element. Clearfix adds `:before` and `:after` as a children, therefore CSS Grid consider them as items.

Remove the clearfix and handle it with following style:

```
float: left;
width: 100%
```