# List in CSS Grid Not Aligning as Expected

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-grid

Problem / Misunderstanding:

I've created an `input type="radio"` for radio choices. The radio choices should align to the left at the beginning of column 3, but instead they are in the middle, between column 3 and 4.

Expected behavior:

Radio input options should be at the beginning of column 3, under aligning with the text input bar of the Name label.

Minimal, complete and verifiable code below.

MCV.html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MCP.css">
<div class="grid-container">
  <form id="survey-form">
    <label for="name" id="name-label">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <div class="radio-title">
      <p>Gender:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-options">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="choice-1">
          <label for="choice-1">Option A</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="choice-1">
          <label for="choice-1">Option B</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

MCV.css code:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  ". . . ."
  ". c c ."
  ". . . .";
  grid-template-columns: 0.7fr 1.5fr 1.5fr 0.7fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.7fr 1.5fr 0.7fr;
}

#survey-form {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: c;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

label {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  text-align: left;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.radio-title {
  grid-column: 2;
  text-align: right;
}

.radio-options {
  grid-column:  3 / 4;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Here's an image with line numbers and form grid:
[image: survey form image with line numbers]

All feedback is appreciated, thank you!

NOTE: This issue was already answered in [How do I remove the first empty column in a css grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128704/how-do-i-remove-the-first-empty-column-in-a-css-grid). Take a look at second answer.

Comment: Please include your [mcve] code within your question, don’t just link to it. This is to guard against link rot and to ensure that your question makes sense, and is useful, without reliance on external sites.

Comment: Will update it in a couple of hours, David. Sorry for my noobness.

Comment: @DavidThomas I've edited the submission and presented MCV as suggested, for future users. Issue is already solved.

Comment: @Michael_B issue is not a duplicate of that answer, since this is really about aligning lists in a css grid.

Comment: @adriaanbd, your comment reinforces the duplicate. Consider reviewing all the answers, not just the accepted one.

Comment: @Michael_B You're right, it is a duplicate. You provided an answer to this issue already. My bad. The question was misleading and I didn't look at all of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is more of a List issue. Most browsers attach some sort of padding / margin to an element so most people clear these out before starting on a new page.

Going to your codepen use:

```
//css
.gender ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

and you'll see the buttons move over to your desired location.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my immediate problem!